# Exceeding a user disk quota. Drive empty but many files in folder

Tags: 20.04, filesystem

df

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       3661495112 67377044 3398750756   2% /home
```

df -i

```
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       976781312 5693471 971087841    1% /home
```

so drive is indeed empty.  I am pretty sure the problem is I have 100 million files in a single folder.  I know there are several reasons this may not be advantageous but it is the reality I have.  I have fixed this before but can't seem to figure out how to get it to allow me to write more files to this folder.

I am running ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The drive has 5693471 files on it.  That doesn't look very empty, that's 5M+ files.   What filesytem type?  Show `df -T` ; and if you are over disk quota, you probably want `quota -v` not df.

Comment: disk quota is just the error.  I have full admin privledges there is no limit except hardware.  and 5 million files on a 4TB drive is not a lot.(-T flag gives same as without)

Comment: `df -T` should show filesystem type, or you can pull it out of fstab.  The filesystem type controls limits and different types have different performance on large directories.

Comment: Thinking about what you said, if disk quota is the error, disk quota is the problem.  You need to look at disk quota and maybe change it.  Add the output from `quota -vs`  to your question anyway.  It is actually important to look at both df and quota.  And filesystem type matters for disk quota too.

Comment: quota is not recognized command.  pretty sure error is just something WinSCP is generate as I am trying to dump more files in then actual error.

Comment: ah missed that it added column with ext4 in it.

Comment: In your question title, you say exceeding user quota.  Where does 'quota' come from? Did you actually get that in an error?  You can have a disk quota without having the tools installed.

Comment: ext4 has severe performance problems with more than about a few thousand files in a single directory.   Check with `du -Shct 1000 --inodes`

Comment: performance isn't an issue in this case because we are always accessing direct and it is a liner data crunching program.  My problem is it won't let me add more and even if i where to rewrite the program to use multiple folders i have large tar files that need to be extracted first.